# TestNG ERROR Cannot find class in classpath, does not work even after clean project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I am trying to run testng form cmd after building the project from cmd as well, but I get the following error:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]  Cannot find class in classpath: (name of testcase file)
```

What I read everywhere is to clean the project from eclipse, I tried but did not work, any ideas about what is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unzip WAR/JAR file and check if you can see the class files.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, my classes are not there!! How can I make the build and include them?

Comment: When you compile the java files they create class files . `% javac Foo.java`. If there are no errors in your source file, the Java compiler will produce one or more .class files (one .class file for each class defined in the Foo.java source file).

Comment: While using Jar please include those class file too. If you are using there is option to select and make fatjar. Please note some of the license doesnot allow you to do this (unless you change the license of your application)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but can you please put an exmple? I don't really know what you mean

Comment: more info about the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345774/build-project-does-not-include-all-the-classes